# Error with Spawned command: npminstall

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to run a sample application from 
https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/.
But I am getting the [error - there was an error with the spawned process: npminstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF3qw.png) every time I try to run the application. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was only to upgrade to new version of npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Spawned command error comes when you try to start a new ionic or cordova app, that gets downloaded from git. This error occurs because your network proxy blocks download a new blank app from git.

To avoid such kind of error try removing the proxies.
1. If you are in a company using their proxy its not possible to do that, so use your own data to do that.

2. Try downloading a blank app from git using your own data, don't use company network which has proxy enabled.
   It will download but while installing the app you will get error like:
   Error with start undefined.
   Error with spawned command npminstall.
   Don't worry a folder will be downloded,

Go to cmd and go inside that app directory and run ionic serve
It will give error like **ionic.config.json** file didn't find.
create a file with the name **ionic.config.json** inside the app file.
inside that file paste the following:
{ "name": "your app name", "app_id": "", "v2": true, "typescript": true }

now try running the command   ionic serve
your app will run.
I had the similar problem but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

install npm globally

```
npm install -g npm
```

create a app without installing its packages

```
ionic start app --v2 --skip-npm
```

seems ok till now?then

```
cd app
```

install packages

```
npm install --save
```

done!try to start your ionic app

```
ionic serve
```